# History vs. Seerah Tags

Tags: discussion

So we have a history tag. Awesome. Should we have a seerah tag too (biography/life of the Prophet)?

If we have history, it can be general and a super-set of seerah. But, I still see value in seerah specifically, which is its own science with its own sources. Which is quite different from, say, asking about the Ottoman empire in WW1.

I already added one seerah tag, so my question is if we should keep it and label other questions accordingly, or if we should dump it.

Answer (score 1):

I think we should keep it, as you said seerah is not like history.  I say we keep the seerah tag and label other questions accordingly.