# Missing seerah tag

Tags: discussion

[This meta post](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310/history-vs-seerah-tags) I posted about a year ago indicates that we had a seerah tag. Where did it go? I can find no mention of it in any other meta question. It seems to have disappeared. (I temporarily re-added it for [my latest question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/9137/statement-about-slightly-lesser-reward-of-abdullah-ibn-rawaha-radillahu-anhu).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an automatic cleanup done on tags; if a tag has only ever been used for a single question, [after six months it will be removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags/48418#48418).  This is easily prevented by either asking another new question, or retagging an existing relevant one, with the new tag.

Comment: Okay. I'll see if I can ask yet another seerah question this month. That will seal it's fate.